# ORACLE APEX - PLSQL statement not bringing back result in field?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

all. I have two fields. One field has a plsql function body that brings back ENAME (employee name) using the EMPNO from the other field. For instance, I put an emp id into one text field and press enter, which brings back the employees name in the other text field.

It's not working and i'm not sure why. I had one error that i corrected, it was an expecting an INTO in my statement. I used the second text-field (P6_NEW_1) where the result/emp name will be. Any help getting this to work would be really appreciated. Also, what does INTO do in this case?

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :P6_NEW IS NOT NULL THEN
    SELECT ENAME INTO :P6_NEW_1 FROM EMP
    WHERE
   :P6_NEW = EMP.EMPNO;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Try changing the P6_NEW item so that is submits the page when enter pressed.  The source of an item is only processed during page load.

Comment: Thank you for responding so swiftly. I hit another issue that I need to resolve before trying this one out. The issue is that my button is no longer appearing in the static content (the button has the submit page & plsql function).